# SummarySE graph does not look right

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
before<-filter(data,Period == "Before")

b4 <- summarySE(before, measurevar="count", groupvars=c("Stream","Year"))

ggplot(b4, aes(x=Year, y=count, colour=Stream)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=count-se, ymax=count+se)) +geom_line() +geom_point()
```

I keep getting the errors and the graph looks super sloppy
[image]

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: Removed 2 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
>
> 2: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

the data is from 1-100, changing the period at 51 from before to after

[image]

Comment: Hi please provide a reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) its very hard to help if we don't know what `before` is

Comment: Add `facet_wrap(vars(Stream))` as another layer.